# Flag consecutive values over a given value in a column. VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

is it possible to Write a VBA code that would flag values over 55 in a Column. here is my simplified example :

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvcq9.png)

I'm looking to have code that would check the Values in the given tables, and when ***3 values over 55 are recorded in a row***, change the color of the "Temp." header from red to green.

Also if possible, calculate the number of days from when the first value > 55 is recorded until the temperature fall back under 55. For the table on the left, that would be DateDiff between B5 and B7.

I just need help flagging consecutive values over 55 in an IF statement or something. Open for other suggestions.

Thanks Overflow Family

Comment: Yes - it is possible to write a VBA code that would do that. I suggest a loop with IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a conditional formatting rule manually or through VBA.

```
Sub greenerPastures()
    With Worksheets("sheet12")
        With .Cells(1, "A")
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="=COUNTIFS(A2:A9997, "">55"", A3:A9998, "">55"", A4:A9999, "">55"")")
                .Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to use that :)